# Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layer" 
    android:src="@drawable/handle"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upper_layer"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_v"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

whenever this code is executed:

```
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_switch, this);
```

I get this error:

`10-29 13:27:00.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22364): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

how can it be?

I have

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: another situation you will find this error is: the dimension is defined in dimens.xml for sw720dp, but it's not defined for devices lower than sw720dp, and you use this dimen var to set the layout_width, and it will crash on devices smaller than sw720dp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these attributes to imageview's

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  // can use dp like 20dp instead of wrap_content
```

**All view groups include a width and height (layout_width and layout_height), and each view is required to define them**.

`wrap_content` tells your view to size itself to the dimensions required by its content
`fill_parent` (**renamed match_parent in API Level 8**) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow.

In general, specifying a layout width and height using absolute units such as pixels is not recommended. Instead, using relative measurements such as density-independent pixel units (dp), wrap_content, or fill_parent, is a better approach, because it helps ensure that your application will display properly across a variety of device screen sizes. The accepted measurement types are defined in the Available Resources document.

Check the link for more info

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to both `ImageView`'s

like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layer" 
    android:src="@drawable/handle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upper_layer"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the first image view will fill the screen since it has match_parent

Comment: yes if you want image will allocate space to only its size then use wrap_content otherwise wanna image in full screen give it to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

If you meet this problem. you ImageView\TextView\Button. they lack of the attribute layout_with or layout_height.
i met this problems when i modified my values/styles.xml/. Because i removed the attribute of android:layout_width.
The original:
`<style name="blue_btn_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">30dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">30dip</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_btn_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/btn_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>`
what i removed the attribute.

```
<style name="blue_btn_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_btn_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/btn_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

so,my code is warning those 
[08-11 18:32:33.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #27: You must supply a layout_width attribute.]

Answer (score 0):

The problem given here leads directly to the line in the XML causing the problem. This error can also happen if a theme is applied to an UI element and the theme is not defining the dimension, here the `layout_width`. E.g. this occurred to me constructing an `AlertDialog` and defining in a style file:

```xml
  <style name="FooBar.DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

<style name="FooBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/FooBar.DialogTheme</item>
        <!-- ... -->
    </style>
```

Adding:

```xml
  <style name="FooBar.DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

solved the issue.